# Kotlin access modifiers

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying and learning Kotlin and came across a confusion with regards to access modifiers, in contrast to Java, Kotlin has Private, Public, Internal and Protected access modifiers,

So is internal same as package ? A small example :

```
package A

private fun foo() {} // visible inside example.kt

public var bar: Int = 5 // property is visible everywhere
    private set         // setter is visible only in example.kt

internal val baz = 6 // visible inside the same module
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, there is a concept of Package but not in Kotlin.

In Java, Package means A is a group of similar types of classes, interfaces and sub-packages.

In contrast to Java, Kotlin has a concept of Module, as per the kotlin documentation , the definition of module is as below :

## Modules in Kotlin

The internal visibility modifier means that the member is visible with the same module. More specifically, a module is a set of Kotlin files compiled together:

1. an IntelliJ IDEA module;
2. a Maven or Gradle project;
3. a set of files compiled with one invocation of the Ant task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This make sense but has some confusion for people coming from java.